# How can i derive step response in terms of impulse response from the convolution sum?

Tags: impulse-response, step-response

If it is discrete LTI system,
How can i derive step response in terms of impulse response from the convolution sum?

Answer (score 2):

In an LTI system, any linear operation on inputs, is directly imposed on the outputs, that is, if an LTI system responses to $\delta[n]$ as $h[n]$, then it responses to $u[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n}\delta[k]$ as $s[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{n}h[k]$.

This is also clear from the convolution since $$s[n]=u[n]*h[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty h[k]u[n-k]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^n h[k]$$

Answer (score 1):

Given a LTI System, $h[n] = F(\delta[n])$

Since 
$$
u[n]= \sum_{k=0}^{ \infty} \delta [n-k],
$$

Step response:

$$
y[n]=F(u[n])=F(\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty} \delta [n-k])
$$

Then, according to Linearity: $f(a \times x + b) = a \times f(x) + f(b)$
$$
y[n] =\sum_{k=0}^{ \infty} F(\delta [n-k]) = \sum_{k=0}^{ \infty} h[n-k].
$$

Comment: Rewriting the final summation as in Mostafa Ayaz’s answer results in a more informative sum than what you have written above.